# jQuery Datatable not loading - SPFX Application Customizer

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, javascript, jquery, spfx

I'm trying to migrate jQuery Datatable from On Prem 2013 to online, I'm gonna create SPFX application extension, where I insert the scripts in order, still datatable is undefined.

```
$.fn.dataTable is undefined
```

I'm using jQuery 1.11.1 and DataTables 1.10.4.

Loading jquery and other files like below in config.json

```
 "externals": {
    "jquery": "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/FileLookup/jquery-1.11.1.min.js",
    "datatables.net" : {
      "path": "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/FileLookup/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
      "globalName": "jQuery",
      "globalDependencies": [
        "jquery"
      ]
    },
    "propertysearch": {
      "path": "https://xx.sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/FileLookup/filesearch.js",
      "globalName": "propertySearch",
      "globalDependencies": [
        "jquery",
        "datatables.net"
      ]
    }
  },
```

Shed me some ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using proper `import` statements & `$` variable initialization like:

```
import 'jquery';
import 'datatables.net';
import 'moment';
```

And

```
var $: any = (window as any).$;
```

Follow this step by step guide which is exactly similar to your requirements: [Migrate jQuery and DataTables solution built using Script Editor web part to SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/migrate-jquery-datatables-script-to-spfx)

Comment: let me check this, the thing is I'm not trying to replicate existing code in SPFx, I'm trying to reference existing JS file scripted for data table implementation